# Separating the non-numeric part of an alphanumeric string

Tags: php, string

I have a set of alphanumeric strings, each beginning with non-numeric characters and ending with numbers, I want to be able to separate the non-numeric parts from the numeric parts, assuming the number of characters is constant for each string, would have been easy but I have strings like ABC123, ABCD456, etc.

Comment: I wrote a script that splited each string after the fourth character, `$str = substr("$str",0,4);` but this wont work for strings with 3-character non-numeric parts

Comment: Is it always 3 numeric parts?

Comment: That's the problem, not always, I stated this in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
<?php
$strArray = array();
$strArray[] = '123ABC';
$strArray[] = 'ABC123';
$strArray[] = 'ABCD456';
$strArray[] = 'ABC4567';
$strArray[] = 'ABCD4567';

foreach ($strArray as $str){
    preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)$/', $str, $matches);
    if (count($matches)===3){
        $alphaPart = $matches[1];
        $numericPart = $matches[2];
        var_dump($alphaPart);
        var_dump($numericPart);
    }
    else{
        echo 'no match: ' . $str;
    }
}
?>
```

I prefer the more specific definition of the pattern to look for. And I do suspect to be preg_split a worse approach, performance wise. At least, I consider it an overkill if there are definitely only two parts to split the string int0.